# How can I detect the neck portion of human face using google vision api?

Tags: android, google-vision

I am trying to explore various face points and add some filters like msqrd/snapchat using google vision api in android.Can anyone help me with detecting the neck portion of the human face?

Answer (score 1):

Simply stated, you can't. But you of course can do some educated guesses.

You have the face outline, with its' size, position, yaw and pitch. The size of the neck is somewhat related to the size of the face and it's always under the face. Knowing that, you can draw an outline. This will not determine if it's f.i. covered by a scarf.

Comment: Is there any other api or frameworks available for neck detection ? Thankyou for the answer.

Comment: I unfortunately don't know.

Comment: Hey @YeshaShah, Have you find any framework for neck detection?